# Calabash-ios console can't start with DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5 (9.2)'

Tags: rubygems, rvm, calabash, calabash-ios, runloop

I am trying to start the test server I am getting the below error. 
Could you please some one give me the solution. I tried different combination of gem versions but no luck.
Appreciated quick help on this.

I am using command something like

```
DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5 (9.2)' calabash-ios console


irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
```

> ArgumentError: Could not find a device with a UDID or name matching 'iPhone'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/device.rb:126:in `device_with_identifier'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/device.rb:160:in`detect_device'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/core.rb:71:in `run_with_options'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop.rb:134:in`run'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:718:in `block in new_run_loop'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:716:in`times'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:716:in `new_run_loop'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:584:in`relaunch'
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.1/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:943:in `start_test_server_in_background'
>       from (irb):1
>       from /Users/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

From your comment, it appears you are trying to launch on a *physical* device, not a simulator.  This is confusing because "iPhone 5 (9.2)" has the same naming convention as a simulator.

When you target a physical device, you need to use the UDID of the device, which you can find in the first few lines of output of `instruments`:

```
$ xcrun instruments -s devices
stern [4AFA58C7-5D39-54D0-9733-04302E7XXXXX]
neptune (9.3.1) [43be3f89d9587e9468c24672777ff6241bdXXXXX]
uranus (9.3.1) [6c3ed5434b5dfc29758f8835644b55bd43XXXXX]
Apple TV 1080p (9.0) [D6875A98-2C0E-4138-85EF-841025A54DE0] (Simulator)
# the rest are simulators.
```

In the example above:

```
* stern is the host computer.
* neptune and uranus are physical devices.
```

To target neptune:

```
$ DEVICE_TARGET=43be3f89d9587e9468c24672777ff6241bdXXXXX \
  DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://<ip of your device>:37265 \
  calabash-ios console
```

If you name your devices sensibly, you can also do this:

```
$ DEVICE_TARGET=neptune \
  DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://<ip of your device>:37265 \
  calabash-ios console
```

I suspect that because your physical device name *exactly matches* a simulator name, Calabash is confused about what device you want to target.

To recap: You have two options:

```
 1. Use the UDID you get from instruments.
 $ DEVICE_TARGET=43be3f89d9587e9468c24672777ff6241bdXXXXX \
   DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://<ip of your device>:37265 \
   calabash-ios console

 2. Rename your device to something like "iphone5"
 $ DEVICE_TARGET=iphone5 \
   DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://<ip of your device>:37265 \
   calabash-ios console
```

You might find the [Testing on Physical Devices](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Testing-on-Physical-Devices) wiki page helpful.

**Previous Answer**

Have you tried `"`quotes?

```
$ DEVICE_TARGET="iPhone 5 (9.2)" calabash-ios console
```

> ArgumentError: Could not find a device with a UDID or name matching 'iPhone' from

For some reason, run-loop is missing the "5 (9.2)" portion of the string.

The only other thing I can think of is that you don't have an iPhone 5 iOS 9.2 simulator installed.  Do you see one in Xcode?

You can also try using the UDID directly.

```
# List the available simulators
$ xcrun instruments -s devices
<snip>
iPhone 6 Plus (9.3) [D6AFEDFE-2E02-4A33-AEC8-740053DDC6DE] (Simulator)

 # Use the UDID directly.
 $ DEVICE_TARGET="D6AFEDFE-2E02-4A33-AEC8-740053DDC6DE" calabash-ios console
```

Comment: After trying with double quotes also i am getting the same error as below:DEVICE_TARGET="A45EB390-9BE5-4B49-A933-E1F91B5334CA" calabash-ios console
Running irb...
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
ArgumentError: Could not find a device with a UDID or name matching 'iphone'
 from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/device.rb:126:in `device_with_identifier'
 from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/device.rb:160:in `detect_device'

Comment: I have connected device using USB and able to see that device in XCODE with name - iPhone 5 (9.2). But still it is not working.

Is there any problem with gem versions?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: I have deleted the simulator and tried to start the test server in background the application is opening and getting the login page but i am not getting next prompt to query my objects , it is waiting at  below step and unable to continue further                 irb(main):002:0> start_test_server_in_background

Comment: If i am opening the app and trying to query the objects i am getting below error:Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (localhost:37265))
Retrying.. Errno::ECONNREFUSED: (Connection refused - connect(2) (localhost:37265))
Failing... Errno::ECONNREFUSED

Comment: > deleted the simulator - you probably should have renamed the device; you might need that simulator later.  > connection refused - You need to set the DEVICE_ENDPOINT.  To see how to do this follow the instructions on the wiki page I linked to in my answer.

Comment: In Xcode i am able to connect the 37265 server and getting following cmds in console:Creating the server: <LPHTTPServer: 0x170140630>
2016-05-12 10:06:14.083 DEBUG CalabashServer:239 | Calabash iOS server version: CALABASH VERSION: 0.18.1
2016-05-12 10:06:14.083 DEBUG CalabashServer:242 | App Base SDK: iphoneos9.2
2016-05-12 10:06:14.083 DEBUG CalabashServer:274 | IPHONE_SIMULATOR_ROOT: (null)
2016-05-12 10:06:14.089 DEBUG CalabashServer:260 | Calabash iOS server is listening on: 192.168.43.163 port 37265

Comment: We are beyond the scope of this question.  Please open a new question.  If I solved your problem, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks for providing the details. I will start other thread for the remaining issue.